# Threejs SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (.glb file)

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I'am trying to learn Threejs and I came across this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFLoader.parse (GLTFLoader.js:213)
    at Object.onLoad (GLTFLoader.js:145)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.module.js:35829)
```

I'am trying to load a Parrot.glb file and console.log it in onLoad function. I know that my web server does not serve a glb file but HTML content ([Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szdju.png)), but what shoud I do next?

For my web sever I'am using Parcel.js...

It is interesting that on the codesendbox it is working properly (it console.log the gltf object): https://codesandbox.io/s/gltfloader-error-mg9in

There is repe on github where you can try it: https://github.com/sleaper/Threejs-test

Thanks for help

Comment: What is the HTML? Is it an error page by any chance?

Comment: nope it is not. The error is in the app.js